# How quickly new infectious viruses can be identified and isolated today?

Tags: virology

Say, tomorrow, a previously unknown disease (with non-unique symptoms) starts spreading: With the techniques we have today, how quickly can we find out which virus might be the root cause?

I am asking this, as I was reading this article about the discovery of HIV:

https://www.pasteur.fr/en/research-journal/news/40-years-hiv-discovery-virus-responsible-aids-identified-may-20-1983

Apparently, it took several years after the epidemiologic observation of AIDS till HIV is isolated and identified as the root-cause. In the case of SARS (2002), this process took less than 5-months:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7112372/

And more recently, for SARS-CoV2, (apparently) it took only 12 days from the first announcement to the genetic sequencing of the virus:

https://www.who.int/news/item/27-04-2020-who-timeline---covid-19

Compared to months/years, identification of the COVID 19 virus within days looks impressive: In the future, can we expect to routinely identify any new infectious virus within days? or cost/effort for these techniques still limit their wider and routine usage?

Comment: Here's a hit: technology, specifically sequencing.